# Python - Instancing classes with a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having trouble doing this.  The following works:

```
def initiate_players(num_players):
    player_list = []
    for i in range(num_players):
        player_list.append(Player("None"))
```

but once I try to add a variable into it, I get nothing:

```
def instance_ports(port_list):
    all_ports = []
    for i in port_list:
        all_ports.append(Port(i))
```

I know there is a way to do this. Sorry, still new.

Comment: What do you mean "you get nothing"?

Comment: Probably, port_list would be empty. print it out and check.

Comment: Why I have a strong inclination to change those functions into `return [Player(n) for n in ['None']*num_players]` and `return [Port(i) for i in port_list]`

Comment: @infgeoax I don't know about you, but for the first one I'd do `return [Player("None") for i in num_players]`

Comment: @infgeoax While I agree, I think the OP is better off sticking to the method he started with for now. He was almost there.

Comment: @BrenBarn Sorry for the ambiguity.
I get:
NameError: name 'all_ports' is not defined

Comment: @infgeoax: Your solution works perfectly.  Can anyone explain why it doesn't work even with return all_ports for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now `player_list` and `all_ports` are local variables. That is, they are only available within the function in which they are defined. Any attempt to use them outside of the function will fail.

Try having your functions [return](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-return_stmt) them

```
def initiate_players(num_players):
    player_list = []
    for i in range(num_players):
        player_list.append(Player("None"))
    return player_list
```

and

```
def instance_ports(port_list):
    all_ports = []
    for i in port_list:
        all_ports.append(Port(i))
    return all_ports
```

Now you can call these from wherever you do your initialization like:

```
num = 5
port_list = [1,3,5,7]
player_list = initiate_players(num)
port_list = instance_ports(ports)
```

Keep in mind, though, that calling these multiple times would not have a cumulative effect, although it appears you only plan on calling them once.

Answer (score 1):

Please declare the way that you used `all_ports` and `player_list`. In the code above, both of them are local variables, you can't use them outside the method. Please add `return` statement. Just like `return all_ports` and `return player_list`, add when you need them, use `all_ports = initate_players(num)` and `all_ports = instance_ports(pl)`.